# How to get all objects from the C-array's pointer of different NSObjects?

Tags: swift, objective-c

I'm using this method to get hidden instance variable with type encoding: [3@] ( all objects are different)

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
#define GETADDRESS(X) (const char *)(__bridge const void *)(X)
#else
#define GETADDRESS(X) (const char *)(X)
#endif

- (void *)getIvarPointer:(NSString *)ivarName {
    Ivar ivar = [self getIvar:ivarName];
    return *(void **)(GETADDRESS(self) + ivar_getOffset(ivar));
}
```

Pointer from return is the first element of array, and I have no idea how to access next members.Arithmetic pointers don't work with NSObject.

```
- (void)pointerToArrayOBJC:(NSString *)ivarName {
    NSObject* firstElement = [self getIvarPointer:ivarName]; // NSDictionary
    NSObject* secondElement = *(n + 128) // Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'NSObject', which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform
}
```

I'd tried to implement this with Swift, however I'm receiving EXEC_BAD, because of the wrong capacity:

```
extension UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
    func toArray<T>(to type: T.Type, capacity : Int, count: Int) -> [T] {
        return Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bindMemory(to: type, capacity: capacity), count: count))
    }
}

func pointerToArraySwift(){
    let firstElement = touchDevice!.getIvarPointer("_reserved3")
    let array = firstElement?.toArray(to: NSObject.self, capacity: 128, count: 3)
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information – these two functions look like they're doing totally different things, and what are `getIvar:` and `GETADDRESS`? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Is the C-array an array of `NSObject` or an array of `NSObject*`?

Comment: @Willeke , array of pointers.Most of values are __NSDictionaryM*, but there are also one id. I'd tried to use struct to wrap array with no luck.Also tried to use *(&pointer + offset) construction, but addresses of of all objects are random.

Comment: How about `NSObject** array = [self getIvarPointer:ivarName]` and `secondElement = array[1]`?

Comment: What's the iVar type? `NSArray`? regular C array (`[NSObject]`)? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Willeke, unfortunately, the second index turns out to be a random element from the heap (I turned off ARC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple, you just need to create wrapper struct with the same elements number as array.

```
typedef struct {
    void* first;
    ...
    void* last;
} reservedArray ;

- (reservedArray)getReservedArray:(NSString *)ivarName{
      Ivar ivar = [self getIvar:ivarName];
    return *(reservedArray *)(GETADDRESS(self) + ivar_getOffset(ivar));
}

- (reservedArray) trace:(NSString *)ivarName {
    return [self getReservedArray:ivarName];
 }
```